# Why SVD cannot recover the original matrix and suffer from numerical instability?

Tags: matrix, stability

I have a matrix in mathematica that looks like

$m=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -i & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -i & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & -1. i \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Note the last element I explicitly use a numerical value of $i$. Now if I use SVD without dropping singular values, I should be able to recover the original matrix:

```
{U, W, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[m]
U.W.Transpose[V]
```

The result however is
$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0.\, +1. i & 0 & 1. & 0 \\
 0 & 0.\, -1. i & 0 & 1. \\
 -1. & 0 & 0.\, -1. i & 0 \\
 0 & -0.6+0.8 i & 0 & 0.8\, +0.6 i \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

If I replace the $1.i$ with the accurate symbol of $i$ there is no problem with recovering the matrix.

What is the reason behind it? Observation shows the matrix $m$ has a non-zero determinant and a close-to-one condition number. I would like to know the properties of such matrix that has issue.

Comment: (1) Best to post full code. (2) Also should check the documentation-- there is no actual issue here.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you have to use `ConjugateTranspose` instead of `Transpose`:

```
m = {
   {-I, 0, 1, 0},
   {0, -I, 0, -1},
   {1, 0, -I, 0},
   {0, -1, 0, -1. I}
   };
{U, W, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[m];
Max[Abs[U.W.ConjugateTranspose[V] - m]]
```

> 4.74287*10^-16

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was fooled by the numerical accuracy stuff and did not think about the complex values.